# how to create a function that selects another object and refreshes in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a function that when clicking the “next” button pass to another random object of my api. But I'm not able to do the function retrieve the other values and update the information in the browser.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    chosenPlanet: 0,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:4000/results'

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.results,
        })
      })
  }
renderPlanet = (event) => {
const planetRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.data)
return planetRandom
}

  render() { 
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.data.length)
    const planet = this.state.data[index]
    console.log(planet)

    return (
      <div className="App">
         <div>{this.planet.name}</div>
        <button onClick={this.renderPlanet}>Next</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In event handlers, state must be updated. State updates causes component to update itself or re-render. In this case, since no state is changed, and only an update needs to be triggered, a forceUpdate can be used.

```
handleNext = (event) => {
  this.forceUpdate();
}
```